# Use Windows/Mac MySQL GUI over SSH Tunnel

Tags: mysql, ssh, ssh-tunnel, tunneling

I am working on a client's website and he has hosting through 1and1. They don't allow connecting directly to their mySQL server from anywhere. I can't for instance load up a mySQL GUI on windows and just connect and work on the databases, it says host not found. His hosting account on the other hand is given access to the mySQL server even though it is in a different location. Let's say these are the servers I'm working with:

**His main hosting:**
Address: thehost.com
Username: joe

**His mySQL server:**
Address: mysqlserver.com
Port: 3306
Database: thedata
User: dbouser

The main hosting account he has comes with SSH. So if I SSH into thehost.com on port 22 and then use the mysql command to connect to mysqlserver.com, it works. I have tried to set up SSH tunneling but the problem is that it's not the mySQL server that has SSH allowed, it's the main hosting. How do I set up SSH Tunneling on both a Mac and a Windows machine so that I can run any GUI I want and I will be able to connect to the mysqlserver.com server. All based on the information above that SSH access is to thehost.com only, and thehost.com itself can connect to mysqlserver.com.

Answer (score 1):

```
ssh -L9999:mysqlserver.com:3306 joe@thehost.com
```

then tell your MySQL Gui to connect to localhost:9999

Answer (score 0):

I think a 50% solution is to use the -Y ssh option, assuming that the host machine has the GUI that you want.

From the ssh man page:

> ```
>  -Y      Enables trusted X11 forwarding.  Trusted X11 forwardings are not
>          subjected to the X11 SECURITY extension controls.
> ```

So from your PC/Mac
`ssh -Y joe@thehost.com`

Then while you're on thehost.com
`joe@thehost.com> /usr/bin/mysql-query-browser`

And add in the mysqlserver.com information. Should funnel the mysql browsing UI back to your Mac/PC.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac, Sequel pro allows you to do by default but I'm still looking for a windows gui client to do it.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Workbench can do the SSH tunnelling for you and it is available on most platforms.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-manage-db-connections-ssh.html
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Answer (score -1):

Assuming MySQL is on standard 3306 port, you just issue this command on Unix/OSX:

```
ssh -L3306:localhost:3306 username@host
```

Then you connect to localhost with your GUI.

Comment: if you are using putty, you can also set it up in its GUI - just follow this document: http://www.cs.uu.nl/technical/services/ssh/putty/puttyfw.html

Comment: Which would work perfectly, unless of course, you actually read the question.